# Cannot read property 'width' of undefined whille converting image into base64?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert my image into `base64` format and send to server .I tried to convert my image base64 but getting error this
**Cannot read property 'width' of undefined**         function

```
getBase64Image(img) {
            // Create an empty canvas element
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            // Copy the image contents to the canvas
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            // Get the data-URL formatted image
            // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
            // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
            // will re-encode the image.
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        }

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}


$(function(){
 // alert()
  $('#fileId').on('change', function (e) {
            console.log('ddd');
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(getBase64Image(handleImage(e)))
        })
})

here is my code
```

https://jsbin.com/zagagivuje/edit?html,js,console,output

I attached one image and try to get base64 string then I am getting this error

Comment: You're defining `canvas` in `getBase64Image`, but you are trying to use it in `handleImage` where it doesn't seem to be in scope.

Comment: can you please suggest the best way actually I want to convert my image into `base64` and send to server to that they will save on `db`

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this [link](https://jsbin.com/yipoxawudi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

What I'm doing here is basically create an image from file url and draw that image on canvas and rest is your code.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  // Create an empty canvas element
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  // Copy the image contents to the canvas
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, img.width, img.height);

  // Get the data-URL formatted image
  // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
  // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
  // will re-encode the image.
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

function handleImage(e, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(event) {
    let r = getBase64Image(img);
    callback(r);
  };
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
}


$(function() {
  // alert()
  $('#fileId').on('change', function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    handleImage(e, function(r) {
      console.log(r);
    });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Return some value from your `handleImage()` function.

Your function `handleImage()` does not return any value. So, when you are doing `console.log(getBase64Image(handleImage(e)))` in the last lines of your code, nothing would get passed in as a parameter for the function `getBase64Image()`. Thus, the value of `img` in the function `getBase64Image()` is `undefined` and so you get the error `Cannot read property 'width' of undefined` when you try to read `img.width` on the third line of your code where `img` is undefined.

Comment: can you please suggest how I will get `base64` string

Comment: Well, I have no idea about that. You should create another post to get the answer to this question of you. But, the bug you are getting is because of the reason I told you.  :)